# Under Nec 2011, I need neutral to every switch box; can I just use 2 14/2's instead of paying extra for 14-2-2?

Tags: electrical, nec

I have two deadend 3way switches planned for the box (on the same breaker). I have 14/3 for each one going on, but then learned of the new rule about needing neutral at every box. I thought to replace one of the 14/3's with 2 14/2's. 3 ways are a bit confusing and this new rule about makes my head spin trying to understand all the outdated diagrams on the net.  Now that I have asked the question, it sort of seems obvious I can do this, but you never know.  thanks

Comment: You want 14/4 for this job if you're using a single cable, *not* 14/2/2...

Comment: hmm; i thought they were the same; HD is callling it 14/2/2 and it has the four wires plus the bare.

Comment: the color coding is different.  14/2/2 is black/white/red/candy-cane (white with red stripe), while 14/4 is black/red/blue/white.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel, if all the OP can find is 14/2/2 is there any  illegality in using it for this purpose, especially if the candy-cane is properly marked as hot? In my area, it's difficult to find 14/2/2, much less 14/4. Using 14/2/2 might be better than using two runs for 14/2 for travelers.

Comment: @mjohns -- You'd have to retag the candy-cane wire as a hot.

Comment: thanks all. I go plain vanilla 3 ways from now on. power-switch-switch-lights

Comment: Just to note: with an X-10 "smart" switch, the slave is connected with a low-voltage signal, not a "hot", so labelling is not as much of an issue.

Answer (score 2):

The Authority Having Jurisdiction (AHJ) might call you on 300.3(B), since not all the conductors are in the same cable.

> ## National Electrical Code 2014
>
> ### Chapter 3 Wiring Methods and Materials
>
> #### Article 300 Wiring Methods
>
> **300.3 Conductors.**
>
> **(B) Conductors of the Same Circuit.** All conductors of
> the same circuit and, where used, the grounded conductor
> and all equipment grounding conductors and bonding conductors
> shall be contained within the same raceway, auxiliary
> gutter, cable tray, cablebus assembly, trench, cable, or
> cord, unless otherwise permitted in accordance with
> 300.3(B)(1) through (B)(4).

You might want to contact the local electrical inspector, or redesign the circuit to avoid the situation altogether.

Comment: +1 The principle reason is the risk of inductive heating if the cable routes through or near any metal boxes or raceways.  When all wires for a circuit are in the same cable, there is a circuit loop (bidirectional) when power flows - no inductive heating. But if there is no return wire (neutral or returning switch loop wire) in the cable, all power is in one direction risking inductive heat buildup. A two wire cable used just for travelers on three way switches is a one way path and not allowed under the code.

Comment: thanks to all for input on this. bib says a two wire cable won't work if just for travelers, but i could put one traveler in each of the two 14/2's, use one common, and have a neutral left over. currently I have a 14/3 going to the dead end (actually two of them. I hope to get a neutral in there and then I'll rethink other 3 ways in the works. pa

Comment: @ShawnBatt, if you use two 14/2 cables you're violating the code in this answer and potentially causing the issue bib described in his comment.

Answer (score 2):

If you're planning the circuit, it sounds like you have some flexibility in what you can do. You could wire your 3-way switches such as to avoid using dead ends. This would make a neutral available at both ends without having to use more than 14/3 between the switches.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Why use 2 wire nuts from N to the bulb instead of solid wire?  Seems like a waste of time just to make the wire weaker.

Comment: @DeanMacGregor in a real-world, in-wall example, it would not be possible to keep a "solid wire" neutral because the cable transitions from 14/2 to 14/3 back to 14/2. It has to have a junction in each switch box. If you were using conduit and THHN this could be possible, but the whole point of this example was to make the neutral available for use in each switch box. If you need to use the neutral in the box, you're going to have a wirenut anyway, which does not make anything about the wire weak.

Comment: Twist-on wire connectors *may* physically weaken the wire, however, it should never matter since there should never be any strain on the wire. If you were falling from a building, and grabbed a wire to save your life. You'd want it to be a solid (unbroken) wire. If the wire is just hanging out inside your walls, it doesn't matter if it's solid (unbroken) or not.

Comment: @DeanMacGregor because the example lets you run regular 3-conductor cable (14/3 or 12/3 NM, for instance) between the boxes, and regular 2-conductor cable into each box. The wire nuts are shown outside the boxes just for illustration, of course. In reality, both of those connections would be inside the boxes. And wire nuts are a totally normal, code-compliant way to connect wires in electrical junction boxes without resorting to any weird wire runs just to avoid using wire nuts.

Comment: Thanks for the schooling.  In the demo it is easy to forget that in real life there's a bunch of drywall and space between the switches.

Answer (score 0):

**Two alternatives:**

> 1. Put the switch loop/leg at the dead-end and tie your neutrals back.
> 2. Run a piece of PVC at the dead-end box so you can add a neutral later without damaging the wall.